# Ajax receives response from server and saves it in a variable for later PhP usage

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

I have an issue, that I cannot solve. I am rather new to Ajax and PhP so I will appreciate any help that I can get.

I have a database on my localhost. What I try to achieve is to get a response from server with information from database. I want to store that information in a variable, so I can later "echo" in certain place.

The whole idea behind this is, that:

You enter product number in an input field. Request is being sent to database. Once you receive response from database, another input field below product number is automatically filled up with a product name. You click on the next step and once again you see the input fields, that are filled up with rest of information based on what product number you entered earlier.

So far the issue is that I can get immediate response once everything is sent, but if I want to see only one piece of information and later "echo" everything else out, but I can't figure how to do that.

I hope that I did manage to explain what is my problem, if not I will try to add more information about it.

This is my Ajax code. I am don't know how to store information that I get from database, so I can use it later on.

```
<script>
function showPump(str) {
    if (str == "0") {
        document.getElementById("pumpInfo").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("pumpInfo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getpump.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

Part of HTML:

```
<form>
    Product number:<input type="text" name="productNR" onfocusout="showPump(this.value)">
</form>
<br>
<div id="pumpInfo"><b>Pump info will be below</b></div>
```

PHP

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"pumps");
$sql="SELECT * FROM pumps WHERE product_nr = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "Product type <input value=" . $row['type'] . "></br>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

End result is that once I fill up the product number field, "result"(Product type) is being displayed right under it, but I have 4 more database entries that I wish to use on next step.

Comment: You might want to call it "display on the DOM" instead of "echo"

Comment: When you say "next step," is the next step on the same page or a different one?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang next step is on the same page, but ofcourse it's not displayed before you finish first step.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to store values that you receive via AJAX.

```
//results will be an array
var results;

if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("pumpInfo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  results.push(this.responseText); //push the value of this.reponseText to the array.
}

//this pops the value of the first element of the results array
alert(results[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Gonna try it out in a bit, but as an additional information, this will store only on one data entry from database? I am searching for a solution to store 4 different data entries in order to use them later on in PhP as an "echo"

Comment: It will store as many as you need. The results are pushed into an array. The more u call, the more it pushes. So for example, when you need the second result, just say result[1]